# extracting portion of string using regexp_substr when it contains ( and )

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I want to extract the the following portion of the string in oracle using regexp:

```
String: FN_SUM(ACCRUED_INTEREST)
Output expected: ACCRUED_INTEREST
```

I tried :

```
select regexp_substr('FN_SUM(ACCRUED_INTEREST)','([^)]') from dual;
```

This gives me ORA-12725 error.

Any solution using regexp would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the literal `FN_SUM`?  Or are you trying to build a more general regular expression to remove, say, arbitrary function names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
select regexp_replace('FN_SUM(ACCRUED_INTEREST)', '(.*)?\((.*)?\)(.*)?$','\2') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks.It works. Didnt know replace could solve it... But, would it be possible to explain this ? i would like to know how you came up with this !

Comment: the ? makes it non greedy. So, (.*)?\( matches FN_SUM(, (.*)?\) matches ACCRUED_INTEREST, and (.*)?$ matches everything remaining.  the \2 grabs the second match (the part inside parenthesis of input)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use conventional replace

```
select replace( replace('fn_sum(value)'
               , substr('fn_sum(value)', 1, instr('fn_sum(value)', '(')))
               , ')') 
  from dual
```

Comment: I already knew this could be done using conventional substr/replace/instr. But, wanted to know the way to do with regexp.